# Assign website to ip address

Tags: networking

I have a server with 2 ip addresses. All the websites are in separate folders in `/var/www/`. For example `/var/www/website1` and `/var/www/website2`.
The nameservers point some of the websites on ip address `12.34.56.78` and some on ip address `90.78.56.34`. All the websites on ip address `12.34.56.78` work but the websites on ip address `90.78.56.34` don't. How do I configure the websites to be on ip addres 90.78.56.34?

Comment: = What does `httpd.conf` show? = What does `etc/hosts` show?

Comment: If it is Apache you are using, you may want to look into the VirtualHost directive (see [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#virtualhost)).

Comment: This is the content of /etc/hosts

Comment: 127.0.0.1 localhost
111.90.150.93 server11362.abc.com server11362

#Virtual Hosts

111.90.150.93  theeducationchannel.info

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

Comment: This is the content of /etc/hosts                                                         127.0.0.1 localhost
111.90.150.93 server11362.abc.com server11362

#Virtual Hosts

111.90.150.93  theeducationchannel.info

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

Comment: httpd.conf is empty

Answer (score 0):

You must change VirtualHost configuration

```
Listen 90.78.56.34:80
Listen 12.34.56.78:80

<VirtualHost 90.78.56.34:80>
ServerName www.example2.com
DocumentRoot /www/website2
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 12.34.56.78:80>
ServerName www.example1.com
DocumentRoot /www/website1
</VirtualHost>
```

Edit 1

```
Listen 90.78.56.34:80
Listen 12.34.56.78:80


<VirtualHost 90.78.56.34:80>
ServerName example2.com
ServerAlias www.example2.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/website2
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 12.34.56.78:80>
ServerName example1.com
ServerAlias www.example1.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/website1
</VirtualHost>
```

I correct path for DocumentRoot and add ServerAlias

Also you change /etc/hosts

```
sudo nano /etc/hosts

12.34.56.78   example1.com
90.78.56.34   example2.com
```

Comment: Which file is it?

Comment: Try with this manual. My english is very bad to explain on better way. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts

Comment: I changed virtualhost configuration as above but websites still do not load